# how I can catch when pressed cancel_url on stripe?

Tags: python, django, django-views, stripe-payments

I have a question about Stripe payments... I figured out how to do some code when payment was succesful, but what and where I can check that user even didn't enter anything in checkout form, and just pressed Back `cancel_url`?

my checkout code:

```
domain = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/profiles/'+username+'/balance/'
            stripe.api_key = settings.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY
            try:
                # Create new Checkout Session for the order
                # Other optional params include:
                # [billing_address_collection] - to display billing address details on the page
                # [customer] - if you have an existing Stripe Customer ID
                # [payment_intent_data] - capture the payment later
                # [customer_email] - prefill the email input in the form
                # For full details see https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create

                # ?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID} means the redirect will have the session ID set as a query param
                checkout_session = stripe.checkout.Session.create(
                    client_reference_id=request.user.username if request.user.is_authenticated else None,
                    success_url=domain + 'success?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}',
                    cancel_url=domain + 'cancelled',
                    payment_method_types=['card'],
                    mode='payment',
                    line_items=[
                        {
                            'price_data': {
                                'currency': 'eur',
                                'unit_amount': grata_points_amount, #6900,
                                'product_data': {
                                    'name': pack.name, #'69 GP',
#                                    'description': 'package with 6900 Grata Points',
#                                    'images': [''],
                                },
                            },
                            'quantity': pack_cnt, #1,
                        }
                    ],
                    metadata={
                        'transactionID': transaction.id
                    }
                )
                return JsonResponse({'sessionId': checkout_session['id']})
            except Exception as e:
                return JsonResponse({'error': str(e)})
```

sucess payment (all needed fields was filled up):

```
def stripe_webhook(request):
    stripe.api_key = settings.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY
    endpoint_secret = settings.STRIPE_ENDPOINT_SECRET
    payload = request.body
    sig_header = request.META['HTTP_STRIPE_SIGNATURE']
    event = None

    try:
        event = stripe.Webhook.construct_event(
            payload, sig_header, endpoint_secret
        )
    except ValueError as e:
        # Invalid payload
        return HttpResponse(status=400)
    except stripe.error.SignatureVerificationError as e:
        # Invalid signature
        return HttpResponse(status=400)

    # Handle the checkout.session.completed event
    if event['type'] == 'checkout.session.completed':
        # TODO: run some custom code here
        session = event['data']['object']
        #getting information of order from session
        userObject = User.objects.get(username=session['client_reference_id'])
        sessionID = session["id"]
        #inform user about successfull payment
        add_notification(userObject, 'bought', 'balance')
        #generate redirect link when payment registered
        domain = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/profiles/' + session['client_reference_id'] + '/balance/'
        return HttpResponseRedirect(domain)
        print("Payment was successful.")

    return HttpResponse(status=200)
```

I'm about button which [is on screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSS0V.jpg)

So any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When users click on the back arrow on the Checkout page, they are redirected to the `cancel_url` you defined. When than happens the Checkout Session is still valid and Stripe won't send you a webhook event. But note that later (usually after 24 hours) the Checkout Session will expire and you will receive a `checkout.session.expired` event.

If you want to know when a user clicks on the back arrow, the only option is to write some custom code on your `cancel_url` page directly.